# How can I add random number into the ArrayList object and decide who cross the line

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add random number 0 to 50 into the each ArrayList object and each 
object will try to reach to the final line `10000` meters.

How can I do that.
Here is my code:

```
private static final int maxDistance = 10000; 
private ArrayList<CarModel> theCar;

public CarController() {

    this.theCar = new ArrayList<CarModel>();     

}
//adding object into the ArrayList

public void addCar(String driverName)
{

    CarModel c = new CarModel(driverName);

     theCar.add(c);

}

// Race Start method

public void raceStart()
{

     while( theCar.size() != maxDistance )
     {
         for(int i=0;i<theCar.size();i++)
         {

            theCar.add(randomWithRange(0, 50));
         }
     }

//random number generated method 

public static int randomWithRange(int min, int max)  
{
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
    return (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

this part is edited code here. here i wanted to get rest of the driver race details with how long they took to finish the race along with winer.

```
public void raceStart() {

    while (true) {
        for (CarModel car : theCar) {
            int carDistance = car.getCarDistance();  
            carDistance += randomWithRange(0, 50);
            car.setCarDistance(carDistance);  

            for (int time = 0; time <= maxDistance; time++)  
            {

                if (carDistance >= maxDistance) {
                    System.out.println("First winner is :" + car.getDriverNames() + "\nTOTAL DISTANCE TRAVELED : "
                            + carDistance + " METERS " + "\nTOTAL TIME TO FINISH THE RACE : " + time);


                    System.out.println("\n\nALL OTHERS COMPETITORS RACE DETAILS");

                    for (int t = 0; t < carDistance; t++) // will find out
                                                            // all other
                                                            // drivers time
                                                            // and distance
                    {
                        System.out.println(
                                "DRIVER NAME :" + car.getDriverNames() + "\nCAR DISTANCE : " + carDistance + "\n");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    return; // Race has finished

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And again, what is the question

Comment: How can I add random number into the ArrayList object and decide who cross the line?

Comment: Infinite loop is here while( theCar.size() != maxDistance ), also you're using wrong approach in raceStart() method.

Comment: I am stack here how can i do that trying to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you should add the field "distance" to your class CarModel and increment it in each iteration:

```
public void raceStart() {
    while (true) {
        for (CarModel car: theCar) {
            int carDistance = car.getDistance();   // Get car's current distance
            carDistance += randomWithRange(0, 50);
            car.setDistance(carDistance);          // And set in back
            if (carDistance >= maxDistance) {
                System.out.println(car.getDriverName());
                return;                          // Race has finished
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPD**
The code above has a logical mistake, because we should finish current iteration to find out who is winner (otherwise participants have different numbers of distance increments). Here is updated code:

```
public void raceStart() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long finishTime;
    CarModel winner = null;
    while (true) {
        if (winner != null) {   // Race has finished
            processResults(winner, finishTime - startTime);
            return;
        }
        for (CarModel car : theCar) {
            int carDistance = car.getCarDistance();
            carDistance += randomWithRange(0, 50);
            car.setCarDistance(carDistance);
            if (carDistance >= maxDistance) {                 
                if (winner == null || carDistance > winner.getCarDistance()) {
                    winner = car;   // We have new winner
                    finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void processResults(CarModel winner, long winnerTime) {
    System.out.println("First winner is :" + winner.getDriverNames() + "\nTOTAL DISTANCE TRAVELED : "
            + winner.getCarDistance() + " METERS " + "\nTOTAL TIME TO FINISH THE RACE : " + winnerTime);

    System.out.println("\n\nALL OTHERS COMPETITORS RACE DETAILS");
    for (CarModel car : theCar) {
        if (!car.equals(winner)) {// need to skip winner
            System.out.println(
                    "DRIVER NAME :" + car.getDriverNames() + "\nCAR DISTANCE : " + car.getDistance() + "\n");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

When at least one car has reached finish, winner reference becomes not null. And we need to break While loop before next cars iteration because race has already finished. Hope you understand my idea

Comment: H iIvan  if (carDistance >= maxDistance) {
              System.out.println("First winner is :" + cm.getDriverNames());
                 return;                               // Race has finished
             }
if i want to output winner of the driver it showed mt null

Comment: What is "cm"? You can call car.getDriverName() where "car" is an object of theCar array and it should have Driver name (if you call addCar function correctly).
Look at edited answer

Comment: yes i changed it and its working but how can i get rest of the driver details with time to finished the rece. I have edited the code.

Comment: Your code has 10.000 unnecessary iterations on each iteration, it's not correct. Just a sec

Comment: Hi Ivan glad to see its pretty much working i have added date and save and load method with that when i write to the file it doesn't seems write properly. and if i want to restart the game i wanted to get the last race result but its only showing the date not result. How can i do that i have edited the code...

Comment: I don't know. May be it's because you don't close ois variable after reading.